# Оператор сравнения в Ruby

Tags: ruby, c++

Для чего предназначен оператор `<=>` в Ruby(да и в других языках)?

Comment: Combined comparison operator. Returns 0 if first operand equals second, 1 if first operand is greater than the second and -1 if first operand is less than the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В перле, например, он заменяет следующее:

```
sub numeric_compare
{
    my ( $n, $m ) = @_;
    return -1 if $n < $m;
    return 1 if $n > $m;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

В Ruby **напрямую** им в основном никто не пользуется. Но его обычно достаточно просто реализовать. После чего с помощью [модуля-примеси `Comparable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Comparable.html) получить разом методы сравнения на **равенство** (`==` и опирающийся на него `!=`), на **порядок**  (`>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=`) и на **принадлежность промежутку** (`between?`). И соответствующие операторы будут работать.

Использовать очень просто: реализовать в своём классе метод `<=>` и в нём же сделать `include Comparable`. И всё, экземпляры этих классов можно сравнивать между собой (или даже с другими типами значений, если реализация `<=>` это позволяет).

В [документации к этому же модулю](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Comparable.html) описаны требования к методу `<=>`:

> The class must define the `<=>` operator, which compares the receiver against another object, returning `-1`, `0`, or `+1` depending on whether the receiver is less than, equal to, or greater than the other object. If the other object is not comparable then the `<=>` operator should return `nil`.

Принимает он один аргумент, а возвращает:

- `-1` если `self` меньше аргумента
- `0` если `self` равен аргументу
- `1` если `self` больше аргумента
- `nil` если `self` невозможно сравнить с аргументом

  - например, сравнение для компл**е**ксных чисел не определено

---

В C++ такого оператора **нет**. И даже аналогичных. Некоторые алгоритмы и структуры данных принимают компаратор, но их возвращаемое значение `bool`, допускает только два значения.

В C себя похожим образом ведёт [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/). Его возвращаемое значение подчиняется менее строгим правилам, чем в Ruby: положено различать случаи, когда результат сравнения *больше* нуля, *равен* или *меньше*. Поэтому его проще всего реализовать, вернув **разность** первых найденных различающихся символов, или ноль, если таковых не нашлось (и нашлись завершающие нули).

Answer (score 0):

В руби можно привести простой пример:

```
a = 10
b = 20
puts a <=> b
```

Если a < b, то выйдет -1;

Если a=b, то будет 0;

Если a>b, выйдет 1;

Answer (score 0):

если для класса можно написать метод <=>, то в него можно включить Comparable

```
class Dog
  # подключает методы <, <=, ==, >= и between?
  include Comparable

  DOG_BARK = {"gav-gav-gav"=>3,"gav-gav"=>2,"gav"=>1}

  attr_accessor :awful

  # <=> меньший слева -1, равны 0, меньший справа 1
  def <=>(other)
    if DOG_BARK[awful] < DOG_BARK[other.awful]
      return -1
    elsif DOG_BARK[awful] == DOG_BARK[other.awful]
      return 0
    else
      return 1
    end
  end
end
```